# Check Checkbox Disabled (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, client-side

The purpose is to;
If checkbox is disabled, do nothing.
If checkbox is enabled and checked, set the style of a button.
Here is what I've got so far;

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {


        $(".checkbox").live("click", function () {

            if ($(this).hasAttribute('disabled')) {
                return false;
            }
            var isAnyChecked;

            $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                var checkedValue = $(this).attr("checked");
                if (checkedValue == "checked") {
                    isAnyChecked = true;
                }


            });

            if (isAnyChecked) {
                $("#<%= btnConfirm.ClientID %>").css("display", "block");

            } else {
                $("#<%= btnConfirm.ClientID %>").css("display", "none");

            }


        });  });
```

I've tried `.is(':disabled')`, `.hasAttr()`, `.prop()` and `.attr()`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For starters, `.live` is deprecated and should be switched out for `.on`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

<s>You have to check whether the `disabled` attribute is true: `.attr('disabled')`.</s>

Or, better, use `.is(':disabled')`.---

---

**EDIT:** So it seems that `.attr` is now deprecated for this use (see http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
The preferred way is:

```
$('#myCheckbox').prop('disabled')
```

It has to be noted that this still work as of today:

```
$('#myCheckbox').is(':disabled')
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Robloche/phaqfrmj/

Comment: No, you have to check for the property: `.prop('disabled')`

Comment: I've also tried on("change", function and not checking disabled completely. That did not work aswell.

Comment: .prop works BUT not when page is loaded. Here is the thing, the grid in the page loads with selectedindex set to 0. When i select something else in the combobox, new items are listed and then the button is shown. But for the first time in page_load it does not work. I've checked the code behind nothing is wrong there tho.

Comment: I made a mistake with `.attr` but it's fixed. Moreover, I tested the 3 solutions (`.attr`, `.is` and `.prop`) and they all work.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try use this:

```
$("#myCheckBox").is('[disabled]');
```

Works for me to determine if an element is disabled.

Possible others solutions (`.disabled`, `.is(':disabled')`, `.attr('disabled')`, `.prop('disabled')`).

Answer (score 0):

for me, this works like a charm to disable:

```
$("#myCheckBox").prop("disabled", true)
```

to enable:

```
$("#myCheckBox").prop("disabled", false)
```