# Check if textbox disabled or enabled in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I check if a textbox is disabled or enabled in JavaScript? I just want to know if a textbox is enable or disabled on button click. If the textbox is disabled I want to alert the user with the message "disabled" and if it is enable, the alert message will be "enabled".

```
<script>
 function CheckTextbox(){

    if(textbox1 is disabled){ //here
      alert("disabled");
    }else{
      alert("enable");
    }

   if(textbox2 is disabled){ //here
      alert("disabled");
   }else{
      alert("enable");
   }
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="textbox1" disabled="disabled">
<input type="text" id="textbox2">
<input type="button" onclick="CheckTextbox();">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821650/check-checkbox-disabled-jquery

Comment: This is a duplicate.

Comment: .disabled works., i just have a wrong id somewhere in my codes. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try using `document.getElementById('textbox1').disabled`

```js
function CheckTextbox() {
  var id;
  for (var i = 1; 2 >= i; i++) {
    id = 'textbox' + i;
    console.log(id, 'is disabled ?', document.getElementById(id).disabled);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox1" disabled="disabled">
<input type="text" id="textbox2">
<input type="button" onclick="CheckTextbox();" value='Check'>
```

Comment: .disabled works., i just have a wrong id somewhere in my codes. but thanks anyway

Comment: idk why this is not working for me, but i did it with: document.getElementById('element').getAttribute('disabled')

Answer (score 9):

**document.getElementById('textbox1').disabled**

```js
function CheckTextbox() {
   var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox1');

   if (textbox.disabled) {
      // If disabled, do this 
       alert("disabled");
    } else {
       // Enter code here
        alert("Not disabled");
     }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox1" disabled="disabled">
<input type="button" onclick="CheckTextbox();">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
function CheckTextbox(){
    var textbox=document.getElementById('textbox1');

if(textbox.disabled)

   {alert("disabled"); }

else{alert("enable");}

var textbox2=document.getElementById('textbox2');
   if(textbox2.disabled){ //here
       alert("disabled");
    }else{
       alert("enable");
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="textbox1" disabled="disabled">
<input type="text" id="textbox2">
<input type="button" onclick="CheckTextbox();">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function CheckTextbox(){

    if(document.getElementById("textbox1").disabled){ //here
       alert("disabled");
    }else{
      alert("enabled");
     }


   if(document.getElementById("textbox2").disabled) { //here
      alert("disabled");
   }else{
      alert("enabled");
   }

}
```

Comment: Accessing the DOM is very slow. You shouldn't use `getElementById()` twice.

Comment: You alert enabled if `.disabled==true`

Answer (score 1):

```
function CheckTextbox(){

    if(document.getElementById("textbox1").disabled == true){ //here
        alert("disabled");
    }else{
        alert("enable");
    }

    if(document.getElementById("textbox2").disabled == true){ //here
        alert("disabled");
    }else{
        alert("enable");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" disabled="disabled">
<input type="text" id="textbox2">
<input type="button" onclick="CheckTextbox();">
<script>
 (function CheckTextbox(){
    if(document.getElementById('textbox1').disabled){
     alert("disabled");
    }else{
     alert("enable");
   }

   if(document.getElementById('textbox2').disabled){ 
    alert("disabled");
   }else{
    alert("enable");
   }
})()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution which is repeated in many answers

`document.getElementById('someId').disabled`

won't work in newer versions of typescript though

Check [Typescript HTMLElement disabled 1.4 to 1.6 what happened (TS2339)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716877/typescript-htmlelement-disabled-1-4-to-1-6-what-happened-ts2339)

Try using

```
let elementToCheck = document.getElementById('someId').attributes.getNamedItem('disabled');

if (elementToCheck !== null) {
    console.log(elementToCheck.value);
}
```

Comment: HTMLElement has .hasAttribute(str), and the attribute value might be present with value enabled, or might it not?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see all responses are deeply tied to `#textbox1` which is bad as your HTML may not always look like that, and states might change.
Secondly, I'd use DOM level 2 event handlers instead of DOM level 0.

Check the BIN below:

http://jsbin.com/hecoyemano/2/