# Typescript HTMLElement disabled 1.4 to 1.6 what happened (TS2339)?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have been working on a TypeScript project using Visual Studio 2013 and the 1.4 version of the TS language. Just now I've upgraded the Visual Studio 2015, which uses TS 1.6.

I have code that uses the "disabled" property of an HTMLElement:
var e: HTMLElement = ...
e.disabled = true;

VS 2015/TS 1.6 now gives me error Code TS2339: "Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Whoa! 'disabled' is a DOM property, and it used to do something in my code, and now it's no longer defined? Where did it go, and how do I deal?

I've carefully read the 'What's New' notes on the TS release from 1.4 to 1.6 but it has nothing to say on this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corresponding to [MDN topics](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), class `HTMLElement` does not have property such as `disabled`. That is why Typescript developers team correct this Web API object

Comment: I see that now, thanks. Interestingly, I had been disabling an HTMLDivElement, and in TS 1.4, that really "did something"... it seemed to auto-cascade to the child elements of the div. But Ok, I'm all for doing things the right way...

Answer (score 6):

The `HTMLElement` interface does not contain the `disabled` property, as it is not a property which has a meaning for all HTML elements. However, it's children `HTMLInputElement`, `HTMLButtonElement` etc. does, because the `disabled` property makes sense with them.

With this in mind, you should be able to correct your code with little trouble.